# BottleNeck/delay when Calling WCF service

Tags: c#, .net, performance, wcf, threadpool

I have created a simple WCF service with a method Do work, which sleeps for 15 seconds and then return a string. Its a Singleton service with multiple Concurrency.

The client(.net Desktop Application)  has a for loop of 100 to call this function. I want to see how many threads i can process at one time and increase performance.

I am using NetTCP binding and have added the performance parameters

Server config

```
<services>
  <service name="WCFService.WCFService" behaviorConfiguration="mexbahaviour">
    <endpoint address="WCFService" binding="netTcpBinding" contract="WCFService.IWCFService" ></endpoint>
    <endpoint address="WCFService" binding="netNamedPipeBinding" contract="WCFService.IWCFService" ></endpoint>
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" ></endpoint>
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8090/ "/>
        <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost:8091/ "/>
        <add baseAddress="net.pipe://localhost/ "/>
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
  </service>
</services>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="mexbahaviour">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
      <serviceThrottling maxConcurrentCalls="300" maxConcurrentSessions="300"
        maxConcurrentInstances="600" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

The issue is the that the request is not hitting the server fast enough. Initial sec there are 4 request, but after that there are 2 requests per seconds. 
[The output window on service looks like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GHNuE.png)

So in this a new thread is created whenever a requests hit the service and logs the time it was received and the goes to sleep.

I did Add connection Management section on the client side

```
<connectionManagement>
  <add address="*" maxconnection="100"/>
</connectionManagement>
```

Is the delay due to thread creation? or some service-throttling limitation that i am hitting?

Please Give suggestions what i do.

I also tried to implement using this article which helped
[Boost WCF Performance](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/133738/Quick-Ways-to-Boost-Performance-and-Scalability-of)

Comment: [Source Code](http://www.filedropper.com/wcfthrottling). It has the Service and client code for testing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, this is based on a basic policy of thread pool. You can modify minThreads as follows,

```
int worker, int io;
ThreadPool.GetMinThreads(out worker, out io); 
ThreadPool.SetMinThreads(worker, 100 - io); // 100 is just sample value.
```

Comment: Actually i did set the Min & Max threads to 500 & 2000. But it did not help. [Source Code](http://www.filedropper.com/wcfthrottling). It has test Server as well as the client application.

Comment: OK, I made a mistake.You have to increase IO threads in this case, not worker threads.

You just modify this line,

ThreadPool.SetMinThreads(_NewMinThreads, _CurrentMinCompPort);

as follows,

ThreadPool.SetMinThreads(_NewMinThreads, 100);

Comment: Thanks that did help, I was able to make max 300 calls simultaneously by increasing the IO threads to 500. do you know how to take it further? Or its better to use Task Parallel Library to increase the simultaneous calls.

Comment: 300 might be depends on <serviceThrottling />, so you can increase by settings them with ThreadPool. Using TPL is not so helpful in this case. Because TPL is also based on ThreadPool.

See this article  [New and Improved CLR 4 Thread Pool Engine](http://www.danielmoth.com/Blog/New-And-Improved-CLR-4-Thread-Pool-Engine.aspx)